# Exploiting Conforming Code Segment access

Tags: x86, operating-system, intel, memory-segmentation

Seeing this in Intel Manual:

> "Conforming segments are used for code modules such as math libraries and exception handlers, which support applications but do not require access to protected system facilities. These modules are part of the operating system or executive software, but they can be executed at numerically higher privilege levels (less privileged levels). Keeping the CPL at the level of a calling code segment when switching to a conforming code segment prevents an application program from accessing nonconforming code segments while at the privilege level (DPL) of a conforming code segment and thus prevents it from accessing more privileged data"

My question is: What would be an example of an application(R3) program trying to exploit the changed CPL(if CPL is changed when accessing a conforming code segment) and access R0 code or data?

I didn't seem to find an answer in the manual.
Would very much appreciate for any help or clue.

Comment: If CPL is changed to a higher privilege when a function is called, the caller can pass pointers to memory that it isn't  allowed to access. To prevent unauthorized access, the function has to check accessibility  of every pointer. With a conforming code segment, the CPL remains that of the caller, so the hardware automatically performs the necessary permission checks.

Comment: Let's assume that CPL is changed from 3 to 0 when accessing this conforming code segment, which is exposed by the kernel, in that way, the segment selector is loaded and the execution is already within the kernel code segment, how can this application (process) from R3 get a chance to access other nonconforming code segment during the execution of some kernel code.

Comment: CPL isn't changed when calling a conforming code segment. If CPL is changed by calling a non conforming code segment through a call gate, then the CPU is no longer in the application; it's in the kernel. So I don't understand your question.

Comment: Do you mean, if conforming code segments aren't used? In that case, any transition to a kernel code segment changes CPL, and the kernel code has to be written to protect itself against exploits. Note that this is how all real OSes work. They don't use conforming code segments. For example, a Linux kernel carefully checks all pointers passed to it by an application before using them.

Comment: See the last sentence "Keeping the CPL at the level of a calling code segment ....... prevents an application......", what would be an example of CPL being changed to DPL of the accessed conforming code segment and then accessing more privileged data